# HyperLink ID Pass with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Can someone give an idea how I can see details of a selected product (suppose) regarding The productID in another page with HyperLink?? I have Tried To pass The ID with QueryString with Linq. But not done.

Comment: any code that you can share to see where the error is , coz usually its passed with the Query params!

Comment: Is the link part of the `gridview`?

Comment: @Dennis yes a part of gridview. I have Tried something as follows: Approve.aspx: (To show all category and products detatils in one page and inside gridview) <asp:HyperLink ID = "View" server = "runat" NavigateUrl = '<%# ("~/pageredirect.aspx") + eval("CatergoryID") %>'>View</asp:HyperLink> pageredirect.aspx.cs: (Selecting specific category and product in another page for details) var ID = Request.Querystring["CategoryID"]; int m = Convert.ToInt32(ID); var con = "from c in context.Categories where c.CategoryID == m select c).ToList(); GridView1.DataSource = con; GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Ok, I get it. Please find my answer below. As noted in my answer you currently have multiple issues in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mark up**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID ="hyperLink" runat="server" />
```

**C#**

Set the url:

```
hyperLink.NavigateUrl = "somePage.aspx?id=123";
```

Read the url query string in `somePage.aspx`

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in your code (as given in your comment section).
Here is what you have

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID = "View" server = "runat" NavigateUrl = '<%# ("~/pageredirect.aspx") + eval("CatergoryID") %>'>View</asp:HyperLink>
```

Issues:

- you have `server = "runat"` and it should be `runat="server"`
- you are concatenating `CatergoryID` with the redirect page and not really passing as   querystring which will really append the value like `pageredirect.aspx + categoryid`
- you are binding as `CatergoryID` and retrieving by query string name `CategoryID` which is not same (notice the typo)

Change your `asp:HyperLink` definition in the itemtemplate of the gridview in `Approve.aspx` as below

```
     <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:HyperLink ID="hlView" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CategoryID", "~/pageredirect.aspx?CategoryID={0}") %>' Text="View" />
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and then in your `pageredirect.aspx.cs` access the querystring value as

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["CategoryID"]))
{
    int m = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["CategoryID"]);

    ....
}
```